# How could I build an Api that returns the video in a byte array?

Tags: pytube

It seams like I can use pytube only in a console application but I wanna use it in a SPA application

How could I build an Api that returns the video in a byte array format so I can call the Api from a SPA application a download or play the video from it.

Thank you!!

Comment: *"It seams like I can use pytube only in a console application"* - How so?

Comment: How could I build an Api that returns the video in a byte array format?